# draw perfect ellipse(circle) using beginShape in processing

Tags: performance, processing, bezier, ellipse

I'm running into speed issues with my processing.js sketch and want to speed it up by creating my 25 ellipses using beginShape() endShape(). I know this has limited functionality but otherwise processing will do a context.beginPath() on every ellipse call like this:

```
function line (x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(x1, y1);
  context.lineTo(x2, y2);
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
};
```

If I could somehow create the ellipses with bezier verteces or with simple curve verteces then I may be able to accomplish this. Has anyone successfully created circles this way? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: I very much doubt you will save any processing resources in this way - Processing is much better at plotting its primitives than user-defined equivalents. If your ellipses are really small you can save resources by plotting octagons instead.

Comment: you're totally right. I realized this after pinning down my performance issues to a few for each loops nested in each other. Turns out I didn't have the latest processing.js version which optimizes these loops. Now it works and I'm capped by my collision algorithm which takes up 99% of the computing power per frame. Gotta start looking at ways to create better collision graphics.

Answer (score 3):

```
void draw() {
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  drawCircle(10,width/3);
}

void drawCircle(int sides, float r)
{
    float angle = 360 / sides;
    beginShape();
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        float x = cos( radians( i * angle ) ) * r;
        float y = sin( radians( i * angle ) ) * r;
        vertex( x, y);    
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
}
```

There is code))